# Firestore serverTimestamp + 24 hours

Tags: javascript, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am implementing a scheduled cloud function that deletes expired documents.

What I am doing in the GCF to upload content with a TTL of 24 hours is:

1. Get the server timestamp
2. Calculate the "expiresAt" date (something like new Date().addHours(24))

Is the right way to get "expiresAt" using the serverTimestamp like this in a google cloud function?

```
 Date.prototype.addHours = function(hours) {
     this.setTime(this.getHours() + hours);
     return this;
 } 

 ...

 const date = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
 const expiresAt = date.toDate().addHours(24);
```

Also, if expiresAt is a Date object, will it be automatically converted to a Firestore timestamp when storing it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If the timestamps are UTC, then adding 24 hours is OK: `new Date(Date.now() + 8.64e7)` because in ECMAScript, UTC days are always exactly 24 hours long. That doesn't work for local timestamps where days aren't always 24 hours long due to DST and historic offset changes. In that case, use `let d = new Date(); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really "get" a Firestore server timestamp.   `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` return a static token value object, not a date.  Those tokens are evaluated on the Firestore server at the time a write happens.

Since you are already running code on a Google backend in Cloud Functions, you can just use the current time as reckoned by JavaScript. It will be the same as the current time in Firestore, but you can do math on it.

```
const now = Date.now()
const expiresAt = new Date(now + 24*60*60*1000)
```